# Whyy can't I declare my animation and configure it?

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why my animation doesn't work. I'm trying to do an animation of a spaceship going through a ring.

Here's my HTML and CSS :

```css
body {
  background: url(Assets/imgs/Stars.jpg);
}

.spaceship {
  height: 70px;
  animation-name: course;
  animation-duration: 30s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes course {
  0% {
    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;
  }

  50% {
    top: 20%;
    left: 80%;
  }

  100% {
    top: 2%;
    left: 90%;
  }
}

.circle-1 {
  height: 200px;
}

.circle-1-2 {
  height: 30px;
}

.circle-1-2 {
  height: 90px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 35%;
}

.circle-2-2 {
  height: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  left: 24%;
  top: 11.4%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Space Conquier</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="spaceship">
      <img
        class="spaceship"
        src="/Users/jeandizian/Documents/Code/space/Assets/imgs/spaceship.png"
        alt="spaceship"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="circle-1">
      <img class="circle-1-2" src="Assets/imgs/circle.png" alt="circle" />
      <img class="circle-2-2" src="Assets/imgs/circle.png" alt="circle" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It's weird because when I add some rotation to it it seems to do a weird movement, but it moves. When I do the code just as I showed in my message, nothing moves.

Thank you

Comment: If i remember img by default is position:static and value as top etc doesn't works. Try to add position:relative and will work

Comment: It does have an effect because now the ship moves but it completely ignores my instructions in the @keyframes

Comment: You should also add `html,body { height: 100%; }` otherwise your body is the size of the initial contents, meaning a value like top 10% gets calculated as 10% of 70px?